# Should I remove firebase debugging for production

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, debugging, firebase-analytics

I have finished my app with firebase and I have been wondering if I should get rid of the -FIRDebugEnabled and the -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled for production. I haven't found anything about this online, anything helps, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Should be reopened. I don't think it's controversial or opinion-based that developer debug logging shouldn't be deployed to end users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You should remove that flag in production builds of your application, as they don't need to send events to the Debug View of the console.

Comment: Thanks, also, when I was testing my app in TestFlight I noticed that banner ads aren't showing up, they are just white. Do you think that could be caused by me not removing the debug flags?

Comment: This flag only determines the way Analytics are reported. I don't think that should affect whether ads are displayed, but I'm honestly not sure what triggers ads.